# Summarize Multiple Factor Columns Grouped by a Character Column and Return Results as a "Nested" Table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, tidyverse

I am stuck on the this issue, which is in theory relatively similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837164/group-by-two-column-and-summarize-multiple-columns), but in practice different enough to cause me headache.

Essentially, I have the following table:

```
str(X)
```

```
 tibble [50,000 x 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ V1          : chr [1:50000] "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" ...
 $ V2          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 ...
 $ V3          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 5 5 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V4          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 5 5 5 3 NA 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ V5          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 1 1 1 1 1 5 4 1 1 1 ...
 $ V6          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 2 1 3 1 5 2 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ V7          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ V8          : Factor w/ 5 levels "***","**","*",..: 1 1 1 NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I am trying to get a table that counts instance of each factor level within each variable and returns the following table (numerical values are made up):

```
V1    V9      V1      V2      V3      V4      V5       V6      V7      V8
M     ***     323     232     44      445     4455     555     555     555
M     **      5555    6446    444     444     4110     899     8       8444
M     *       323     232     44      445     4455     555     555     555
M     .       5555    6446    444     444     4110     899     8       8444
M     ns      323     232     44      445     4455     555     555     555
F     ***     5555    6446    444     444     4110     899     8       8444
F     **      323     232     44      445     4455     555     555     555
F     *       5555    6446    444     444     4110     899     8       8444
F     .       323     232     44      445     4455     555     555     555
F     ns      5555    6446    444     444     4110     899     8       8444
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
X %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -V1, names_to = "Name", values_to = 'V9') %>%
   count(V1, Name, V9) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

As per request in the comment, I'm including another look at the data:

```
dput(head(X,5))
```

```
structure(list(V1 = c("M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()` or `dput(head(YourData, 30))`.

Comment: @MartinGal, I have included the data. Albeit, akrun has already provided a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, get the counts and reshape back

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
X %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -V1, names_to = "Name", values_to = 'V9') %>%
   count(V1, Name, V9) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

#### data

```
X <- structure(list(V1 = c("M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("***", 
    "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("***", "**", "*", ".", "ns"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!!! Thank you so much! I will accept the answer in 9mins (due to time buffer).

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I meant to edit the question, but I accidently messed up your answer.

Comment: @FranjoIM its okay.  I rolledback the edit. Thanks for the headsup